# Ordering Datagridview Column by Date that was saved as NVarChar

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, sql-order-by, date-conversion

I have a table in my database with columns ID, Name, Leave, and Date and I can view these using the datagridview and I saved them all in NVarChar Data Type because there is a part in what I'm working that I can save the date as "Present" and I want  to order the columns by Date in Descending order. The format of the date was "**MM/DD/YYYY**"

I used these codes to order the columns:

```
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[3], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

and it orders it like this:

[image]

It orders the first digit of the date but as you can see, the **YEAR** of the date is not in descending order.

I tried to convert the DATE column in **datetime** format.

I used this SQL query to convert the **NVARCHAR to DATETIME**

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Date, 101) from DateTable
```

But it displays the Date and Time and only displays the DATE column.

I really need some help here.

Comment: In your sql server query add  `order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,10) desc`

Comment: no luck. It still only order the first digits

Comment: Where is your query which selects data for gridview ?

Comment: this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.leaveDatabaseDataSet.Employees);